# laravel and vuejs post method

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I need your help I'm making a shopping cart in laravel with vuejs.

I have the following problem I am new to vuejs I am inserting products from a component A where is my form in vue I insert it but I have no response in my component B where is my table where the products are registered, be careful if you add the detail is that I have to reload the page to see that the number of products increased.

I am using EventBus from vuejs

I hope you can help me thanks for any help

this is my form

```
<form method="post" v-on:submit.prevent>
    <input :value="csrf" type="hidden" name="_token" >
    <input :model="ProductSearch.id" name="id" type="hidden" class="form-control input-lg">
    <input :value="ProductSearch.name" name="name" type="hidden" class="form-control input-lg">
    <input :value="ProductSearch.sale_price" name="precio" type="hidden" class="form-control input-lg">
    <input :value="1" name="cantidad" type="number" class="form-control input-lg" min="1" style="text-align:center" >
    <button v-on:click="addproduct" class="btn btn-info btn-block" name="btnAccion" value="Agregar" type="submit"> Add</button>
</form>
```

This is my method

```
addproduct: async function () {
        axios.post('sales/item', {
            id: this.id,
            name: this.name,
            precio: this.precio,
            cantidad: this.cantidad,
        })

        .then(function(response){
            
            EventBus.$emit('agregado', response.data)
        })
        
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.response);
        });
    }
```

this is my table where I reflect my result.

```
<tbody >
<tr v-for="(ProductCart, index) in carrito" :key="index.id">
<td>{{ProductCart.name}}</td>
<td>{{ProductCart.cantidad}}</td>
<td>{{ProductCart.precio}}</td>
<td>{{ProductCart.cantidad * ProductCart.precio}}</td>
<td> 
   <form  method="post">
   <input :value="csrf" type="hidden" name="_token" >
   <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="" >
   <button  class="btn btn-danger" type="submit"> Remove</button>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th colspan="2"></th>
<td>
<h5>Total</h5>
</td>
<td align="right">
<h5>{{ total }}</h5>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

scrip of component of the table

```
data(){
        return{
            csrf: document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content,
            carrito: [],
        }
    },

created(){
    EventBus.$on('agregado', data => {
        this.carrito.push(data)
        

    })
},
```

in my console I receive the error:
Error in event handler for "agregado": "TypeError: _this.carrito.push is not a function"

Comment: How are you informing `Component B` that it needs to update it's data?

Comment: @Unflux indeed posted the right question. It seems like everything is working except for the fact you need to refresh your page to see the changes in component B right? After your successful post to the backend from component A you could for example emit an event, with an EventBus, or maybe even go as far as implementing a `veux store`. https://andrejsabrickis.medium.com/https-medium-com-andrejsabrickis-create-simple-eventbus-to-communicate-between-vue-js-components-cdc11cd59860

Comment: @MaartenVeerman  I opted for EvenBus but it sent me an error, Error in event handler for "added": "TypeError: _this.cart.push is not a function"

Comment: You need to either post a new question or updates this question, make sure to show your code.